# need to combine to lists in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

the two lists to be passed to the view from controller.

```
ViewBag.mylist1 = new Accounts().List(Category.Income); 
ViewBag.mylist2 = new Accounts().List(Category.Expenditure);
```

HOw to combine thse two lists in a single view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myList1 = myList1.Concat(myList2).ToList();
```

Concat returns an IEnumerable that is the two lists put together, it doesn't modify either existing list. Also, since it returns an IEnumerable, if you want to assign it to a variable that is List, you'll have to call ToList() on the IEnumerable that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `AddRange()`

```
ViewBag.myList1 = ViewBag.myList1.AddRange(ViewBag.myList2);
```

[`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) modifies the list by adding the other items to it.

[`Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) returns a new sequence containing the list and the other items, without modifying the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SelectListItem> lstFuelType = new List<SelectListItem>();
var FuelType = dbContext.APPL_COMMON_MST.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable().Where(cm);
lstFuelType = new SelectList(FuelType, "KEY", "VALUE").ToList();
lstFuelType.Insert(0,new SelectListItem { Text = "ALL", Value = "ALL", Selected = false });
ViewBag.FuelType = lstFuelType;
```